# DNS temporarily fails with VPN addresses

Tags: dns, vpn, dnsmasq

I'm connecting to a company network on Lubuntu 15.10 with vpnc either on terminal or via the network manager. Sometimes I can reach the intranet hosts fine, then suddenly they are gone. Then they come back. I don't change anything on the settings, my connection is otherwise stable. It's very frustrating.

I can usually always reach them via their ip but not their host name. 
Here is the output of dig only 5 minutes apart, one time it fails the other time it doesn't.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-11ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> some.intranet.host
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 7423
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some.intranet.host.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
some.intranet.host. 3500    IN  A   10.0.20.107

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 10 18:46:17 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

---

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-11ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> some.intranet.host
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 17766
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1280
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some.intranet.host.        IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 10 19:06:35 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

I'm not good with network setup and struggle to debug it.
The content of my resolv.conf when connected to the vpn:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search intranet.host intranet fritz.box
```

---

```
ifconfig tun0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.16.0.138  P-t-P:172.16.0.138  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1412  Metric:1
          RX packets:46575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:45875777 (45.8 MB)  TX bytes:4059895 (4.0 MB)
```

---

**Update:**

Despite deactivating dnsmasq I can see a running process after reboot and my resolv.conf still holds 127.0.0.1 as nameserver.  After I kill the process I cannot resolve web addresses anymore. I assume I would need to take out the nameserver from resolv.conf manually then?

```
$ grep dnsmasq /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
#dns=dnsmasq

$ ps aux|grep dnsmas
dnsmasq   1730  0.0  0.0  49580  3052 ?        S    16:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working setup now for the same client/vpn situation under Debian bullseye/sid/unstable is to take out NetworkManager from the equation.

1. Remove NetworkManager (you probably won't be able to connect to Wifis by the regular tray icon GUI then!)

   sudo apt remove network-manager-gnome network-manager
   sudo apt install dnsmasq
2. Use a simple custom dnsmasq config.

File: /etc/dnsmasq.d/your-name

```
# Use my router as default
server=192.168.2.1
# Use some-company dns for intranet hosts
server=/some-company.com/10.49.123.5
server=/.foo/10.49.123.5
```

Optionally add these two lines for debugging via the logs:

```
log-queries
log-dhcp
```

Docs at: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Dnsmasq/

2. Make sure `/etc/resolv.conf` is not a symbolic link and make it point to dnsmasq. That's important because the vpn scripts up/down scripts may try to change the file and mess up your configuration on connect/disconnect.

File: /etc/resolv.con

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

YMMV: Since I still saw something override my /etc/resolf.conf I added a line to the end of /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

3. Restart services

   /etc/init.d/networking restart
   sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart

This finally makes it work for non-company and company addresses when I'm connected or not connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntus ship with `dnsmasq` enabled as a default. Dnsmasq is 1) a DNS caching proxy (for performance) and 2) a DHCP server. I cannot find a reason why a typical home user talking to a typical home router would need dnsmasq to duplicate these two services that your router provides.

The first step is to disable dnsmasq:

```
$ grep dnsmasq /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
#dns=dnsmasq
$ sudo service network-manager restart
$ sudo killall dnsmasq
```

Before anything else, it would be a good idea to confirm that your network connectivity remains unchanged. If you see a performance hit in DNS, I'd be surprised.

Fire up `vpnc`; I run it manually also, no NetworkManager aid for me. You may have to re-point the default route to your VPN. You can find the VPN tunnel pseudo-device with `ifconfig`; mine is named `tun0`

```
$ sudo route del default ; sudo route add default tun0
```

I suggest keeping them on one line in case having no default router jams up your terminal (it shouldn't, but...).

The first code block above is done once. The default route, if it needs to be changed at all, needs to be done every time you VPN. I have simple script that does all this which I'm not posting here because without better understanding of NetworkManager I consider it too localized.

Comment: Thank you msw, I already commented out dnsmaq a long time ago, but curiously there is still a dnsmasq process getting started on reboot. I will kill it and see if it helps.

Comment: That's odd. Prior to the kill, I did `ps -C dnsmsq` to get the PID and `strace -p PID` to demonstrate to myself that it was doing nothing (and it wasn't). Could you do the same? I'll fire up a Lubuntu 15.10 and see if I can confirm.

Comment: The instructions for stopping dnsmasq above worked on an out-of-the-iso Lubuntu 15.10 (64bit) installation. The interesting question then becomes, is `dnsmasq` active? Check `/etc/resolv.conf`, nameserver should **not** be localhost.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the effort. I noticed a typo in your command, it should be  `ps -C dnsmasq`  I assume. I added an update to my question answering yours. :)

Comment: So edit the resolv.conf, expect it to be overwritten if dnsmasq is running. There are at least three ways that daemon could be started, which probably makes for a new question. The apt package `dnsmasq-base` contains no code that should auto-start it.

Comment: I tried to add the nameservers manually after killing dnsmasq but it still failed. My solution now is adding those machines to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Not having a live DNS server is not a solution. Open a new question. Over and out.